# HTML popover fix

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have table with popover link, like this.

[image]

and when it's mouse over it's like this

[image]

Do anyone have idea how to make that popover does not cover the price, actually does not enter the next column but is in the same
Here is the code.

```
<div class="condition-title">
    <a data-toggle="popover" data-html="true"
       data-content="{{ $rate->description }} 
         @include('components.book.popover_fees', ['fees'=> $fees]) 
         @include('components.book.popover_advance_payment', ['rate' => $rate, 'type' => 'activity'])">
                            {{$rate->name_frontend}}
        <i class="glyphicons glyphicons-question-sign"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: you can make it appear on top or at the bottom. i am sure there is some info about that in the popover documentation

Answer (score 1):

Add  `data-placement="top"`. See docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/#four-directions

```
<a data-toggle="popover"
   data-placement="top"
   ...
>...</a>
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

```css
.condition-title {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="condition-title">
  <a  data-toggle="popover"
      data-placement="top"
      data-html="true"
      data-content="content">
                           Click to reveal
   <i class="glyphicons glyphicons-question-sign">i</i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```